How to convert units when calculating a dimensionless quantity?
For instance, consider calculating this quantity:
$$
P= \frac{1}{H^4~~ } \times  \left(\frac{1}{k_0}\right)^{0.2} ~~(1),
$$
where $H$ and $k_0$ are constants in units of GeV and Mpc, respectively. How do we convert or choose units to make $P$ dimensionless,
where Mpc$^{-1} = 6.6 \times 10^{-39}$ GeV?
The original quantity is given in this paper: reference, equations: (31-33-34), where $a(\eta)= \frac{1}{H\eta}$, so I considered in (1) only the constants which share by dimensions to $P$.
Any help is appreciated!

If P is dimensionless, it means that the constants in the equation have to be expressed in the analogous units to nullify dimensions

so is $H$  a constant in GeV?...or anything with units of $E = [M][L]^2[T]^{-2}$? If yes, then calling out the dimension with an extra $(GeV)^4$ is only going to cause confusion. Re-ask with no units in the equations, dimensional constants explained properly. Also, the power should be a fraction: $\frac 1 5 $.

The original Equation is:
$$
P_\text{old}= \frac{1}{H_\text{old}^4~~ (GeV)^4} \times  \left(\frac{1}{k_\text{0 old} ~~~(Mpc)^{-1}}\right)^{0.2} \tag{1}
$$
So to make $P_\text{new}$ dimensionless, the following terms need to be rescaled.

Since $\left(\frac{1}{k_\text{0 old} ~~~(Mpc)^{-1}}\right)$ is being raised to the $0.2$ power, it is most likely a dimensionless quantity already. The reference has a summary that did not elucidate that detail further.  So $k_\text{0 new}=\frac{k_\text{0 old}}{1 Mpc}$.
$\frac{1}{H_\text{old}^4~~ (GeV)^4} $ needs to be dimensionless. So assign $H_\text{new}={H_\text{old}}*{1 GeV}$.  With this assignment, it follows that $P_\text{new}$ is dimensionless as desired and:
$$
\boxed{P_\text{new}= \frac{1}{H_\text{new}^4} \times  \left(\frac{1}{k_\text{0 new} }\right)^{0.2}} \tag{2}
$$


Thanks for the answer. So it's simple like that. Can I ask another thing please, assume I don't want to use $H = 10^{14}$ (GeV) and I want to use instead $H = 10^{-4}$ (unit) , what should I do ? there is now a factor $10^{-18}$, such that $10^{14} \text{GeV} =10^{14} \times 10^{-18} \text{unit} = 10^{-4} \text{unit} $, how this affect on the equation, or will the  factor $10^{-18}$ multiplied by the equation ?

The new unit needs to be determined against the old unit.  $10^{14}(GeV)=10^{-4}(New)$ so $(New)=10^{18}(GeV)$.  Then just make the calculation in $(GeV's)$ and then divide by $10^{18}$ to get the value in the new unit.

Does it mean if $P \sim \frac{1}{H^4_{new}}$ like (2), when it converted to "Unit", it will be  $P \sim \frac{1}{H^4_{new}} \times (10^{-18})^4  $?

It seems your question is contradictory. You start saying that P is dimensionless, then you want to convert it to make it dimensionless. If it is already dimensionless, then no conversion is needed.
Assuming P has a dimension D, you could add a constant C with dimension D so that the new quantity P'=P/C becomes dimensionless.

It depends on the field of science where the formula is used. E.g., if it is about the study of echo's in mountains, or the Doppler effect of sound, probably the velocity of sound is a nice constant to scale other velocities and make velocity dimensionless. In other studies it might be the velocity of light.

enhanced the question to make it more clear. It's such a basic idea, like when asking about how to make the velocity which equals (meter/sec) dimensionless quantity, so if there is any system units where L→T
which is the natural units.

The equation 31 in the reference cited is:
$$ P(k)=\frac 4 9 \Delta^2_R (k_0) \left( \frac k {k_0}\right)^{n_s-1}   $$
$P$ and $\Delta^2_R$ are both dimensionless and $k$ in Mpc$^{-1}$ is scaled so as to be in a dimensionless ratio.
So I may not be following your question well, but it seems to be creating a difficulty that does not exist in the original.
